# MonacaアプリのiCloudへのバックアップ

Tags: javascript, ios, onsen-ui, angularjs

単純な質問なのですが、Monacaで作ったアプリはiCloudでバックアップ可能とありますが、どのデータをバックアップするのでしょうか？
Localstrage内にある、WEB SQLやIndexedDBにあたるのでしょうか？